# Extract a specific text in between 2 characters in a line from a text file using Python

Tags: python

Here is some of the content of my log file:

```
2021.08.09.11.32.35.7795, General, connected?, connected, operation state, connecting, laser state, Standby, pulse picker trigger, internal, Amplifier LD current in mA, 0, PP Frequency in kHz, 10000, System Reset, 65535, Bust Mode, 1, Modelock, no, Oscillator Ready, not ready, Front-end Ready, ready, current in mA, 0, temperature in deg C, 26, power in mW, 37, Pulse Picker Frequency in kHz, 0, Laser ON Runtime in hour, 1894, Laser Head Humidity in %, 42, Laser Head Temperature in deg C, 26, Two Photon Diode in mV, 12, Laser Power in mW, 34, Error Code, 0, Laser FW Version, 7.4.6, TcpModbus protocol version, 1.1.4, state, Null, On, FALSE, Good, FALSE, Fast Blank, FALSE, Treating, FALSE, Error, FALSE, Error Detail, (No Error)
2021.08.09.11.32.45.7868, General, connected?, connected, operation state, connecting, laser state, Standby, pulse picker trigger, internal, Amplifier LD current in mA, 0, PP Frequency in kHz, 10000, System Reset, 65535, Bust Mode, 1, Modelock, no, Oscillator Ready, not ready, Front-end Ready, ready, current in mA, 0, temperature in deg C, 26, power in mW, 34, Pulse Picker Frequency in kHz, 0, Laser ON Runtime in hour, 1894, Laser Head Humidity in %, 42, Laser Head Temperature in deg C, 25, Two Photon Diode in mV, 11, Laser Power in mW, 34, Error Code, 0, Laser FW Version, 7.4.6, TcpModbus protocol version, 1.1.4, state, Null, On, FALSE, Good, FALSE, Fast Blank, FALSE, Treating, FALSE, Error, FALSE, Error Detail, (No Error)
2021.08.09.11.32.51.0936, General, connected?, connected, operation state, connecting, laser state, Standby, pulse picker trigger, internal, Amplifier LD current in mA, 0, PP Frequency in kHz, 10000, System Reset, 65535, Bust Mode, 1, Modelock, no, Oscillator Ready, not ready, Front-end Ready, ready, current in mA, 0, temperature in deg C, 26, power in mW, 37, Pulse Picker Frequency in kHz, 0, Laser ON Runtime in hour, 1894, Laser Head Humidity in %, 42, Laser Head Temperature in deg C, 26, Two Photon Diode in mV, 11, Laser Power in mW, 34, Error Code, 0, Laser FW Version, 7.4.6, TcpModbus protocol version, 1.1.4, state, Null, On, FALSE, Good, FALSE, Fast Blank, FALSE, Treating, FALSE, Error, FALSE, Error Detail, (No Error)
2021.08.09.11.32.55.8040, General, connected?, connected, operation state, connecting, laser state, Standby, pulse picker trigger, internal, Amplifier LD current in mA, 0, PP Frequency in kHz, 10000, System Reset, 65535, Bust Mode, 1, Modelock, no, Oscillator Ready, not ready, Front-end Ready, ready, current in mA, 0, temperature in deg C, 26, power in mW, 34, Pulse Picker Frequency in kHz, 0, Laser ON Runtime in hour, 1894, Laser Head Humidity in %, 41, Laser Head Temperature in deg C, 26, Two Photon Diode in mV, 11, Laser Power in mW, 34, Error Code, 0, Laser FW Version, 7.4.6, TcpModbus protocol version, 1.1.4, state, Null, On, FALSE, Good, FALSE, Fast Blank, FALSE, Treating, FALSE, Error, FALSE, Error Detail, (No Error)
```

I want to extract the below data into a text file, based on the above data:

```
Date and Time               Amplifier LD current in mA   Two Photon Diode in mV
---------------             ---------------------------- ------------------------
2021.08.09.11.32.35.7795    0                            12
2021.08.09.11.32.45.7868    0                            11
2021.08.09.11.32.51.0936    0                            11 
2021.08.09.11.32.55.8040    0                            11
```

Also, I need to extract other parameters as well, like:

- current in mA
- temperature in deg C
- power in mW
- Laser Head Temperature in deg C
- Laser Power in mW
- Fast Blank

There may be as many as 10,000 lines of data in the text file. I would like to know the best way to use a Python script to extract this data. Here is a portion of my code I tried:

```
file_path = r"Laser-20210809-113225.log" 
outFile = open("result.txt", "w")

with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    size = len(content)
    start =0
    for line in file_path:
        start = content.find(" Two Photon Diode in mV,",start)
        start = start if start != -1 else size
        end = content.find(", Laser Power in mW", start)
        end = end if end != -1 else size
        print(content[start+1:end])
        outFile.write(content[start+1:end])
        outFile.write("\n")
        start = end + 1
outFile.close()
```

But I got stuck, when I tried to get the Date and Time data, which is towards the start of the line.

Comment: I have removed the `powershell` tag from your question as it doesn't seem to be related. Re-add it if you consider it should be there.

Comment: Your data is effectively a .csv file - have you looked at `csv.reader`?

Comment: Dry code logic: 1. Read the file as pandas DF (with csv). 2. Loop through each column first cell, if it matches with your search "string" 3. Add the whole next column to a new DF; where the column of new DF will be search "string" and rows will be rows of next column. #Only "Date and Time" will always be 0th column.

Comment: Thanks, @SantiagoSquarzon. I added PowerShell, thinking there might be a possible solution in PowerShell.

Comment: @Grismar thanks for the comment, actually no, I did not. Will look into it.

Comment: @SHYAMTHILLAINATHAN no worries, there is a powershell solution since it shares some similarities with python but since you didn't mention anything related with PS I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is in the `csv` format. Python has a built-in library for helping read csv's: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

I just printed out the results but of course, you could write the results to a file.

```py
import csv

with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        print(row[0], row[11], row[39])
```

You can also provide column headers to avoid the ugly numbers to access the correct columns. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader for details.

If you want additional features and to do more manipulation with the data, Pandas is a great library for this type of data. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html would help you get the data in.

Comment: Currently, the file format is *.log, do I need to convert it into *.csv (or) as it is will work?

Comment: It will work as is. Your log file has comma-separated values (csv) and the file is plain text so the `csv` library will have no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest manner to do this is using the `.split()` method of strings. In each iteration of that `for`, you can use `data=line.split(',')` to break the entire line into several "segments", each one between a pair of commas or the end of line (you can substitute the `','` for any other char/string to break lines according to other chars).

Using this approach, `data[0]` would contain the time/date, `data[1]` would contain the string "General", `data[2]`  would contain "connected?", and so on.

Finally, you just need to write down the `data[]` using the proper indices as follows: `outFile.write(data[0] + "," + data[1] + "," + data[2])`

Just remember to verify the index of the columns you want to save based on the input file, and use the proper index when writing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did add the `powershell` tag on your question and I removed it (*feeling guilty*) I guess I could show you how this could be done using PS.

This will result in an object that you can easily manipulate, for example:

```
PS /> $result.'Date and Time'
2021.08.09.11.32.35.7795
2021.08.09.11.32.45.7868
2021.08.09.11.32.51.0936
2021.08.09.11.32.55.8040

PS /> $result.'Date and Time'[2]
2021.08.09.11.32.51.0936

PS /> $result.'temperature in deg C'
26
26
26
26

PS /> $result.Where({$_.'Laser Head Temperature in deg C' -eq 26}) | Select-Object 'Date and Time','Laser Head Temperature in deg C'

Date and Time            Laser Head Temperature in deg C
-------------            -------------------------------
2021.08.09.11.32.35.7795 26                             
2021.08.09.11.32.51.0936 26                             
2021.08.09.11.32.55.8040 26
```

The code would look something like this:

```
$raw = @'
2021.08.09.11.32.35.7795, General, connected?, connected, operation state, connecting, laser state, Standby, pulse picker trigger, internal, Amplifier LD current in mA, 0, PP Frequency in kHz, 10000, System Reset, 65535, Bust Mode, 1, Modelock, no, Oscillator Ready, not ready, Front-end Ready, ready, current in mA, 0, temperature in deg C, 26, power in mW, 37, Pulse Picker Frequency in kHz, 0, Laser ON Runtime in hour, 1894, Laser Head Humidity in %, 42, Laser Head Temperature in deg C, 26, Two Photon Diode in mV, 12, Laser Power in mW, 34, Error Code, 0, Laser FW Version, 7.4.6, TcpModbus protocol version, 1.1.4, state, Null, On, FALSE, Good, FALSE, Fast Blank, FALSE, Treating, FALSE, Error, FALSE, Error Detail, (No Error)
2021.08.09.11.32.45.7868, General, connected?, connected, operation state, connecting, laser state, Standby, pulse picker trigger, internal, Amplifier LD current in mA, 0, PP Frequency in kHz, 10000, System Reset, 65535, Bust Mode, 1, Modelock, no, Oscillator Ready, not ready, Front-end Ready, ready, current in mA, 0, temperature in deg C, 26, power in mW, 34, Pulse Picker Frequency in kHz, 0, Laser ON Runtime in hour, 1894, Laser Head Humidity in %, 42, Laser Head Temperature in deg C, 25, Two Photon Diode in mV, 11, Laser Power in mW, 34, Error Code, 0, Laser FW Version, 7.4.6, TcpModbus protocol version, 1.1.4, state, Null, On, FALSE, Good, FALSE, Fast Blank, FALSE, Treating, FALSE, Error, FALSE, Error Detail, (No Error)
2021.08.09.11.32.51.0936, General, connected?, connected, operation state, connecting, laser state, Standby, pulse picker trigger, internal, Amplifier LD current in mA, 0, PP Frequency in kHz, 10000, System Reset, 65535, Bust Mode, 1, Modelock, no, Oscillator Ready, not ready, Front-end Ready, ready, current in mA, 0, temperature in deg C, 26, power in mW, 37, Pulse Picker Frequency in kHz, 0, Laser ON Runtime in hour, 1894, Laser Head Humidity in %, 42, Laser Head Temperature in deg C, 26, Two Photon Diode in mV, 11, Laser Power in mW, 34, Error Code, 0, Laser FW Version, 7.4.6, TcpModbus protocol version, 1.1.4, state, Null, On, FALSE, Good, FALSE, Fast Blank, FALSE, Treating, FALSE, Error, FALSE, Error Detail, (No Error)
2021.08.09.11.32.55.8040, General, connected?, connected, operation state, connecting, laser state, Standby, pulse picker trigger, internal, Amplifier LD current in mA, 0, PP Frequency in kHz, 10000, System Reset, 65535, Bust Mode, 1, Modelock, no, Oscillator Ready, not ready, Front-end Ready, ready, current in mA, 0, temperature in deg C, 26, power in mW, 34, Pulse Picker Frequency in kHz, 0, Laser ON Runtime in hour, 1894, Laser Head Humidity in %, 41, Laser Head Temperature in deg C, 26, Two Photon Diode in mV, 11, Laser Power in mW, 34, Error Code, 0, Laser FW Version, 7.4.6, TcpModbus protocol version, 1.1.4, state, Null, On, FALSE, Good, FALSE, Fast Blank, FALSE, Treating, FALSE, Error, FALSE, Error Detail, (No Error)
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$i=0

$result = $raw | ForEach-Object {

    $arr = $_ -split ',' -ne ''
    $col, $val = $arr[2..($arr.Length-1)].where({
        if($i = -not $i){$_}
    },'Split')
    
    $out = [ordered]@{}
    $out.Add('Date and Time',$arr[0].Trim())
    $out.Add('General?',$arr[1].Trim())

    for($z=0;$z -lt [math]::Max($col.Count,$val.Count);$z++)
    {
        $out.Add($col[$z].Trim(),$val[$z].Trim())
    }

    [pscustomobject]$out
}
```

**Note:** The `$raw` variable is there just to test the code, however, since you're reading a `.log` file, you should read it using `Get-Content`:

```
$raw = Get-Content 'absolute/path/to/Laser-20210809-113225.log'
```

Lastly, this is how the `$result` object looks like when using `Out-GridView`:

[image: $result|Out-GridView]

Comment: Thank you so much, however, I am having trouble though, I used Windows PowerShell to execute it, and when I execute it, I don't get any output. Should I be using any command at the end that I am missing to see here. Sorry for the trouble and thanks a lot for the really needed help.

Comment: @SHYAMTHILLAINATHAN did you see if the variable `$result` is populated? Just do `$result` and press enter in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked, thanks all for your help, really appreciate:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time
import datetime

pd.set_option('display.max_rows',10000)

timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
file_start = r".\output_"
extension = ".csv"

file_name = file_start + timestr + extension

outFile = open(file_name, "w")
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sthilla1\Downloads\2021-08-09\11-32-25\Laser-20210809-113225.csv', usecols = [0,25,26], low_memory = True)
outFile.write(str(df))
outFile.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

For getting the date you can use regular expressions:

```
import re

text = "2021.08.09.11.32.35.7795 text text text 2001.02.01.12.35.55.7795"

regex_pattern = "[0-9]{4}(?:\.[0-9]{2}){5}\.[0-9]{4}"

date_list = re.findall(regex_pattern, text) #to get many ones

date = re.search(regex_pattern, text)[0] #to get only one

print(date_list)
print("-------")
print(date)
```

result:

```
['2021.08.09.11.32.35.7795', '2001.02.01.12.35.55.7795']
-------
2021.08.09.11.32.35.7795
```